# Vim open/close slowly in remote computer due to sourcing a file

Tags: linux

Vim works (open/close) slow in remote computer. Other tasks such as giving basic commands like `ls` works faster. Compilation is also slow. In the output of `vim --startuptime`, there is a jump in time due to sourcing a file.  Is there anything to do to speed up vim?

```
419 061.563  000.422  000.422: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
420 4196.809  000.483  000.483: sourcing /home/doe/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle.vim
```

Comment: Presumably Vundle, a plugin manager, is loading all your plugins during that time. Regardless, if the remote system is slow there's nothing you can do about it through Vim which is fairly well optimized. (`ls` running fast doesn't say anything about the performance, btw. Slow compilation is more meaningful but not a proper test either. If you want to dig deeper google linux benchmark tests or something along those lines and run on the remote and another system with known performance profile and compare.)

Comment: @BLayer Even worse is slow startup happens sometimes but vim always quits super slow. Don't know how to debug slow quit.

Comment: Well, if you just have a slow system I'm not sure what value there is to debugging that. But note that on startup Vim is mostly reading from disk while on shutdown there are more (expensive) writes (even if you don't save a file there is swap file removal and, depending on configuration, writing to other files, e.g. viminfo). It's possible that on this system disk reads are sporadically slow but writes are always slow.

Comment: Consider editing locally using something like netrw